# When compiling a project, Maven throws an error

Tags: java, maven-3

OS Linux - Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
When compiling a project, Maven throws an error

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper
```

java -version

```
openjdk version "17" 2021-09-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17+35-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

mvn -version

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 17, vendor: BellSoft, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java17-amd64
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.11.0-37-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep 'java.home'

```
java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java17-amd64
```

Comment: There are many Linuxes. Which distro and version are you running? 

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue. Sadly I just could update to 3.6.3 via the package manager so I installed it manually. Steps to install on ubuntu below:

Maven 3.3+ requires JDK 1.7 or above to be installed.

Download Apache Maven. I installed 3.8.6, you can check for the newest version here: https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

We save the archive to `/tmp`

```
$ TMP_MAVEN_VERSION=3.8.6
$ wget https://apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/$TMP_MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$TMP_MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz -P /tmp
```

Then unzip it to `/opt` and remove the archive

```
$ sudo tar xf /tmp/apache-maven-*.tar.gz -C /opt
$ sudo rm /tmp/apache-maven-*-bin.tar.gz
```

Next we create a sym-link

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/apache-maven-$TMP_MAVEN_VERSION /opt/maven
```

Lastly we set up the env

```
$ sudo echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
export M2_HOME=/opt/maven
export MAVEN_HOME=/opt/maven
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}" >> /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
```

To use it without restarting we make it executable and run in

```
$ sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
$ source /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
```

Now you can verify that it is properly installed

```
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 11.0.13, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.11.0-1022-aws", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

[derived by](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-apache-maven-on-ubuntu-20-04/#disqus_thread)

Answer (score 3):

Same issue i also faced.And i got the solution. Update latest maven version which is 3.8.3. With latest maven it is working.

```
mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.8.3 (ff8e977a158738155dc465c6a97ffaf31982d739)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 17, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.10.0-1051-oem", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021/10/25, maven is not supporting Java 17.

Create `vi ~/.mavenrc` file and give any version lower than 17.

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/`

Comment: it didn't work here...

Answer (score 0):

I met the same mistake as you. my os version is `ubuntu 20.04 LTS` .

the reason is maven version(3.6.3) is old.

download lastest bin version (apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.zip) from https://maven.apache.org

i decompress files to `/data/app/maven/3.8.6/apache-maven-3.8.6/bin`

using command like this `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/ &&  /data/app/maven/3.8.6/apache-maven-3.8.6/bin/mvn`

it works well on my machine